# Javascript browser prompt asks twice the same value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just learning the javascript and react. I have created a sample code to run.

```
function App() {
      return (
       <div>
         {fun()}
       </div>
  );
}

function fun() {
  var me = window.prompt("me","")
  var she = window.prompt("she","")
  return(
    <div>
      {me} and {she}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But the problem is, the browser prompt asks each me, and she values twice and uses the 2nd value in the function. Please help me to fix this.

I have tried to take the values from other function also, but I think the page reloads after giving the first couple of inputs.

Comment: React will re-render your components whenever it wants. If you want side-effects (like a window prompt) to not re-run, you will need to put them in a useEffect hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practices would be to move side effects (like window prompts) to a `useEffect` call. That way, combined with a couple state variables (`useState`), you can ensure that you are only prompting the user one set of times and it'll stay in memory as long as the component is mounted.

The other thing I wanted to address is that you should make things like that `fun` function a component instead of a loose function. There's not much difference, just a capital letter, but it lets you use it as a Component instead of a function.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  return <div><Fun/></div>;
}

function Fun() {
  const [me, setMe] = useState("");
  const [she, setShe] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setMe(window.prompt("me", ""));
    setShe(window.prompt("she", ""));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {me} and {she}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, app);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id=app>
```

Comment: Thanks, Zachary Haber for the instructions. Thank you for remembering me about the availability of components. As I have little experience in Vanilla JS, I often use functions instead of components in React also. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you used create-react-app to create your project, it's very much likely that your index.js file looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

> React StrictMode renders components twice (on dev but not production) in order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them.

Just remove that React.StrictMode and you will see prompt appearing just two times as you wanted. Make your code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <App />
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't

```js
function App() {
      return (
       <div>
         {fun()}
       </div>
  );
}

function fun() {
  var me = window.prompt("me","")
  var she = window.prompt("she","")
  return(
    <div>
      {me} and {she}
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,app)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id=app>
```

Comment: Yes, It doesn't in the snippet. But it happens in the local browser. I have checked with multiple browsers and the problem remains the same.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it. It was due to the React.StrictMode in the index.js file. In production, there were no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Delete React.StrictMode from Index.js and that should solve it. Thank you AJITHKUMAR S!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).